# Formatting @BindView code

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

Android Studio by default format Butterknife code in this way:

```
@BindView(R.id.text_view) 
TextView mTextView
```

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to format code in one line, like this:

```
@BindView(R.id.text_view) TextView mTextView
```

If this is possible I would like this rule to apply only to `@BindView` annotation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in Android Studio 2.3.3
File -> Settings -> Editor ->Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Field annotations -> set to "Do not Wrap"

but this will prevent AS to put the new line on all field annotations.

i don't know if it is possible to have this option only for @BindView, however, if you set the option like this, AS will not put all annotations inline. for instance if you have

```
@Nullable
String foo;

@BindView View bar;
```

and format the code, AS will leave both annotations as they are.